# <script> command not working

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have code that has a section like this in it:

```
<c:if test="${prodCd != null and prodCd != ''}" > 
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test='${prodType == "BOOK"}' >
            ${prodType}
            <script>
                alert("before Overlay");
                doOverlay(650,0,'Download eBook');
                alert("do Overlay");
                getThePart('overlay-content','http://<%=myHost%>/servlets/bookandchaptersDetails.do?prodcd="${prodCd}");
           </script>
       </c:when>
  </c:choose>
</c:if>
```

It will print off "Book" so I know I am falling into that loop, but for some reason, my alert (and the subsequent parts of the script) isn't popping up when the page loads.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unbalanced quotes here:

```
getThePart('overlay-content','http://<%=myHost%>/servlets/bookandchaptersDetails.do?prodcd="${prodCd}");
```

It results in syntax error, so the code is not executed at all.
Change it to:

```
getThePart('overlay-content','http://<%=myHost%>/servlets/bookandchaptersDetails.do?prodcd="${prodCd}"');
```

Pay attention for the single quote I've added in the end of the line.

Comment: There's the problem, thank you so much. Knew it had to be something simple I just wasn't seeing.